# Showing that the series for $\zeta(z)$ defines a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

[image]

I was told that is the Riemann Zeta function, but I'm very stuck on where to  begin a mathematical proof of this question and I would greatly appreciate any help to understand the question and where to begin.

Comment: Do you know the theorem of Weierstraß that the limit of a locally uniformly convergent sequence of holomorphic functions is again holomorphic?

Comment: I believe so, in the form of Morera's Theorem.

Comment: Hmm, Morera's theorem is about something else. Although it can be used for an easy proof of Weierstraß' theorem. Anyway, knowing that, you can 1. show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ the function $z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic (on all of $\mathbb{C}$), and then 2. show that the series converges locally uniformly on the half-plane $\{z:\operatorname{Re} z > 1\}$. For the latter, find $\lvert n^z\rvert = n^{\operatorname{Re} z}$, and use the $M$-test to see the series converges uniformly on $\{z: \operatorname{Re} z \geqslant 1+\varepsilon\}$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: is it not neccessary to use the note in the question?

Comment: Well, you need it to know what $n^z$ means.

Comment: how can you show that the function $\frac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic, when n>0 and $Re(z)>1$?

Comment: You know that the function $z \mapsto e^{a\cdot z}$ is holomorphic (on the whole plane) for every fixed $a\in \mathbb{C}$, I suppose. Choose an appropriate $a$.

Comment: so is there a way to prove that $\frac{1}{n^z}$ is holomorphic? would you put it into the form $e^{−zlogn}$ and then use the condition for holomorphicity $f′(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$, as i want to show that it is holomorphic rather than just saying that it is.

Comment: @DavinaGoodman it is obvious that $e^{- z\ln n}$ is holomorphic in $z$, with any definition of the complex exponential

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Infinite_sums_and_integrals

Answer (score 0):

When $Re(z)>1$, we have that
$$\zeta(z) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n^z} = \lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\int_1^x u^{-z}du -z\int_1^x \{u\}u^{-z-1}du -\frac{\{x\}}{x^z}).$$ This follows from an application of partial summation, where $\{u\}$ denotes the fractional part of $u$. We then have that this equals

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{1-z}(x^{-z+1}-1)-z\int_1^x \{u\} u^{-z-1}du -\frac{\{x\}}{x^z}) =\frac{1}{z-1} +1-z\int_1^\infty \{u\}u^{-z-1} du$$

The integral on the right is absolutely convergent when $Re(z)>0$, and we have that $\zeta(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=1$, so we have that $\zeta(z)$ is holomorphic whenever $Re(z)>1$. We have in fact shown more than that; we have shown that $\zeta(z)$ is meromorphic where $Re(z)>0$.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use the Abel summation formula, where showing that for $Re(s) > 1$ : $\zeta'(s) =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \ln n$ is obvious so it is holomorphic

Comment: I guess it's a little bit stronger. There's definitely a simpler way to show it, this was just the way I've seen it proved the most.

Comment: Showing that $\int_1^\infty \{x\}x^{-s-1}dx$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) > 0$ is not easier than showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) > 1$ (well the proofs are exactly the same, see my answer)

Comment: A little more difficult : showing that $\int_1^\infty (\{x\}-1/2)x^{-s-1}dx$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) > -1$ (useful for proving the functional equation, since $\{x\}-1/2 = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n}$)

Answer (score 0):

What is asked is to say that $f_n(z) = n^{-z} = e^{-z \ln n}$ is holomorphic with derivative $f_n'(z) = -e^{-z \ln n} \ln n$.

Also $$\left|f_n(z+h)-f_n(z) - h f_n'(z) \right|= \left|\int_z^{z+h} (f_n'(u)-f_n'(z))du\right|=\left|\int_z^{z+h} \int_z^u f_n''(v)dv du\right|$$
$$ \le \int_z^{z+h} \int_z^u \sup_{|w| < |h|}|f_n''(w)|dv du<|h|^2\sup_{|v| < |h|} |f_n''(z+v)| =|h|^2 n^{|Re(h)|-Re(z)}\ln^2 n $$

Now since for any $\epsilon > 0$ : $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-\epsilon}\ln^2 n = 0$

you have that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{|Re(h)|-Re(z)}\ln^2 n$ is bounded when say $Re(z) > 1+\epsilon$ and $|h|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$,

and with $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(z) $ : 
$$\left|\frac{ \zeta(z+h)-\zeta(z)}{h} - g(z)\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left|\frac{ f_n(z+h)-f_n(z)}{h} - f_n'(z)\right| < |h| \sum_{n=1}^\infty   n^{-1-\alpha}\ln^2n $$
i.e 
$$Re(z) > 1 , \qquad\qquad \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\zeta(z+h)-\zeta(z)}{h} = g(z)$$
so that $\zeta'(z)= g(z) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-z} \ln n$ and $\zeta(z)$ is holomorphic on $Re(z)  > 1$.

Comment: how did you derive that $hn^{-Re(z)} ln^2 n$ was greater than $|\frac{n^{-h} -1}{h} -lnn| |n^{-z}|$ ?

Comment: @DavinaGoodman I meant the idea is that $|\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}-f'(z)| < |h|^2 f''(z)$ ;D